Can’t use a custom login page with Identifier First
I want to universal login to build a login page that verifies the email domain first and then prompts for the password. I followed the instructions in this post,; I turned off the the Customize Login Page toggle, but it still didn’t work. I chose the prompt method to login-id, but it always reverts back to the login prompt, which prompts the email and password fields at the same time,  after refreshing the page. I also selected the identifier first option to ensure it prompts for the email field first, but it still didn’t work.[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/7oERYOYe.png)

I set the authentication method to be Identifier First, which is the login screen prompts users for their user email, then a different screen prompts users for their password.

I turned off the the Customize Login Page toggle.


